# publishing and hosting the webservice on cloud

Tags: java, web-services

I have web service that is up and running that is in other words it is publish on my tomat on port 8080 and I can hit it through my browser now I want that my webservice to be get published on cloud so that I can pass wsdl uri to any one in the world and he can access my wsdl. Please advise how to achieve this ..!!will Amazon provide such facilities.

Comment: You can definitely do that on amazon cloud. But if you are using it for elasticity, you may not want to publish ec2 uri.

Comment: @javausersoma..could you please explain in detail a little bit . so that understanding can be made..!!

Comment: when you setup an amazon ec2 instance you do get its public ip and hostname. So you can run your webservice there just like your run in your system and hence publish your wsdl. That should answer your question. At the same time if you are using ec2 for elasticity, ie spinning up servers and terminating them based on load etc, publishing your wsdl with ec2 host will be a concern.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried various options and Amazon's [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) is the most seamless. You can launch your Java webservice by simply uploading a war. However, it does require an EC2 instance to be running.

Other options are [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) and [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/)

Heroku has a free tier and uses Maven/Git to deploy the app to their server. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-a-java-web-application-that-launches-with-jetty-runner

Windows Azure also has instructions on how to deploy a java webapp on their platform. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/

Given these options, In my personal opinion, the cheapest is Heroku and the most convinient is Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.